# Boot problems in install

Tags: installation, usb-drive

I had windows 8 running on my computer and decided that I wanted to swith over to using ubuntu. I used my USB drive and downloaded the 13.10 edition. The. I used the PendriveLinux software from the site to put the ubuntu install onto the USB drive to make it bootable. Then I turned off my computer and rebooted it with the USB drive. I went through the installation steps and installed it and made an ubuntu one account. Then it prompted me to restart my computer. I restarted it with the flash drive still in and it rebooted to the same installation page that's black. So I turned off and turned on my computer without the flash drive plugged in and it didn't boot it just said start PXE over IPv4. I waited a while and I got a no operating system message. Can someone PLEASE help me figure out this problem and how I can get the OS up and running?

Comment: I really need some help with this so it would be great of someone could help me out

Comment: check the booting order in your BIOS; hard disk first, then PXE

Comment: How do I check that? When I boot the computer with no flash drive in, it doesn't boot it goes straight to the start PXE over ipv4 message

Comment: maybe you should press F2 (or F10, or... ) it depends on your hardware, there's no general rule. check the manual.

Comment: I tried pressing F2 and f10 to pull up bios settings but none of that pulls that up.

Comment: you have to press F2 ( or F10 or ...) when the computer boots

Comment: There is no boot process though. I press the "on" button the computer box and it immediately goes to the start PXE screen

Comment: which computer model did you are using?

Comment: i am using a lenovo

Comment: The best place for additional information is to edit your question instead of adding comments.  Comments do get deleted eventually. [This page](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-52236) may help you get to your BIOS settings so you can check the boot order.

Comment: There was a seperate `nova` button was there on the lenovo laptop to boot into bios,Which was just near to the power plugin port.please check it.

Answer (score 0):

u bttr try pressing delete key constantly to enter into bios.and then check the boot priority ,change first boot priority to Hard Disk and second to CD- ROM .. thats it, if still problem persist then please try to reinstall ubuntu and this time make sure u have removed pendrive b4 restarting..